# Abinitio : Writing data to a target table

Tags: ab-initio

I am new to Abinitio and I need help for the following.

Table 1  has columns :

Col1

Col2

Col3

Table 2 has columns :

col 4

col5

I am using join component and also reformat component and got the output as  col2,col3,col4,col5. And  I am writing this to a target table which has

id, col2,col3,col4,col5 ,created_by, created_date_time,last_modified_date.

As  I have data for col2,col3,col4,col5 from output of the join component but not for id,created_by, created_date_time,last_modified_date.

How do I add this using abinitio. Any help on this is greatly appreciated and apologize if this kind of basic question was alread discussed.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You could connect REFORMAT component to the output flow of the JOIN component. Transform function in the REFORMAT component could pass the col2, col3, col4, col5 values using wildcard rule out.* :: in.*. The rest of columns in the output table should be present in the DML of the output port of REFORMAT component as well, so then you could assign data to these columns in the transform function in the REFORMAT, e. g. out.created_by :: "something".

Answer (score 0):

After join component connect the reformat component and in the ports section of reformat component change the dml for output port by adding all the relevant columns you need to have in the output then change the transform function of reformat component as follows:
1. for all the incoming values of join use out.* :: in.* 
2. for all the additional columns that you have added in the out port of dml assign value using out.column_name ::  "value you need to pass"

Answer (score 0):

In join component,simply you could write transformation for  all the required columns. Include  id,created_by, created_date_time,last_modified_date in output port dml(embedded) of join .For col2,col3,col4,col5 you can map from respective  input columns and  for id,created_by, created_date_time,last_modified_date add required transformation.  So you could avoid one extra reformat component .